# Navigation Bar & Navigation Toolbar NOT from App Delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

I'm new to xcode ios 7.
I've struggling a lot with navigation controls building app for iPhone ios7.
I don't want to use storyboard. I prefer to do it programmatically.

What i am trying to do.

I know how to create `NavigationBar` & `Navigation Toolbar` via `AppDelegate.m`

But if it's possible i don't want to do it, because let's assume i want in *FirstViewController* to show just simple button "Go to Second View Controller" (No Navigation Bar or Toolbar here).

And now in *SecondViewController* i want to create Navigation Toolbar (bottom) with 4 different tabs linking to `ViewControllers`!

But the trick is, i want to maintain different Navigation Bar (top) for every `ViewController` (as you can see in this screenshot).

Here is my [Xcode Project File](https://assets.tyxo.co/NavApp.zip)

And here is screenshot form Fancy app showing what i am trying to achieve.[image: Example]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, When you tap the button on your first view controller, you can create a UINavigationController and set your second view controller as its root view controller. This way, your first view controller remains no nav bar view and the second view controller holds a Navigation controller. Try something like below:

```
-(IBAction)goToSecondVC:(id)sender // An action for the button in your first VC
{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; //Init with second view controller
    UINavigationController *secondNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC]; // create a navigation controller and set the root as your second view controller
    [self presentViewController:secondNavVC animated:YES completion:nil]; // and then present it with anim or no anim..
}
```